# Изменить только внешний вид (состояние) checkbox. C#

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня `checkbox` и `timer`. `checkbox` выполняет некий код (если программа запущена, он её убивает. А если нет, то запускает). И есть `timer`, который управляет состоянием `checkbox'ом` (от состояния программы). Но есть проблема, когда код в `timer'e` обнаружил, что программа обнаружена, то он меняет состояние и происходит выполнение кода в `CheckedChanged`. И программа сразу убивается.

Вопрос, как изменить только внешний вид (состояние) checkbox?
`checkbox.CheckState = CheckState.Checked` и `checkbox.Checked = true` не помогают.

Comment: У вас проблема с кодом, но код вы не показываете. Не видите тут противоречий?

Comment: Прежде чем менять состояние чекбокса нужно отписаться от события `CheckedChanged`, потом поменять состояние чекбокса и снова подписаться на это событие.